# Segmentation fault when printing copy of array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, segmentation-fault

The following program segfaults when `v2` is printed but not during the array copy. Does anyone know why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void cpyarray (void* dst, void* src, size_t memsize, size_t size) {

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        *(((char*) dst) + i*memsize) = *(((char*) src) + i*memsize);
    }
}

int main () {

    size_t N = 10;

    double* v1 = (double *) malloc(N * sizeof(double));
    double* v2 = (double *) malloc(N * sizeof(double));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) *(v1+i) = i;

    printf("\n\nv1: ");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) printf("%g ", v1[i]);

    cpyarray(&v2, &v1, sizeof(double), N);

    printf("\n\nv2: ");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) printf("%g ", v2[i]); // program crashes here

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**: the code does not crash if I copy arrays of `ints` instead of `doubles`.

Comment: You should use "void*" instead of "char*". Btw, you are always only copying 1 character..

Comment: @user1548637: I might be wrong, but as far as I know you cannot add values to `void*` (pointer arithmetic is not defined for `void*`).

Comment: @curvature - except with gcc, which offers this as an extension; it treats `void*` as if it were `char*` for pointer arithmetic. :-(

Comment: D: Damn gcc. Thanks for telling me

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using such code in C++ ? This is very C-style and C++ provides much more polished tools for that job.

Comment: Replace `cpyarray` with `memcpy`. The standard library can do this much better than you can.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I'm trying to practice concepts here instead of using functions from stdlib.

Comment: You should check your loops as well. You count from 0 to 10 but there are only 10 elements not 11.

Comment: There is no problem with the loop?

Comment: oh right no problems in the loops, sorry. But, in plain C you are supposed to declare the counter variable outside of the loop (before C99).

Comment: @Alexander: I used `-std=c99` to compile my code with gcc (after getting a compilation error related to what you said).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v1`, `v2` are pointers to memory blocks that you want to operate on. But you're passing their *addresses* to your `cpyarray` function.

So you're operating on the wrong memory blocks, stepping on memory around the `v2` variable, and changing what `v2` points to.

```
cpyarray(v2, v1, sizeof(double), N);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `&v2` to `cpyarray()`, which means that your function is changing where `v2` is pointing! Since it's now pointing to an invalid location, you get a seg fault when you dereference it for `printf()`.

Instead, just pass `v2` to `cpyarray()`.

Comment: Ugh, I can't believe I did this. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, now that I'm considering the comment of user1548637: how does the program know how much memory I am copying at each iteration of the `for` loop?

Comment: @curvature Your program doesn't know the actual size since you've cast it to a `char*`. Ie, you're copying only one byte per iteration. But that doesn't matter since the first iteration kills your pointer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing wrong pointers to `cpyarray` function.

Your code sends pointer to array (pointer to pointer to double)

```
cpyarray(&v2, &v1, sizeof(double), N);
```

You should send array instead (pointer to double)

```
cpyarray(v2, v1, sizeof(double), N);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the problem that the current answers have pointed out, `cpyarray` doesn't copy the array, just some parts of it. Instead of trying to imitate types with `i*memsize`, just treat the memory block as a bunch of bytes and copy them one by one. Now all you have to do is figure out how many bytes to copy, which isn't hard.

Comment: Yes, I fixed that by inserting another `for` loop which does byte by byte copy for each element.

Comment: @curvature - that's doing it the hard way, and may be slower than just running through the bytes.

Comment: Since its an array, you only need one loop! Don't read further if you don't want to see an example: `for (size_t i = 0; i < (size*memsize); ++i) *(((char*)dst)+ i) =  *(((char*)src)+ i);`